# Dump tcp port to file on W10 without netcat

Tags: tcp, netcat

I use this netcat command:

```
nc 192.168.1.67 7 >test.txt
```

to dump raw data from port 7 on 192.168.1.67 to local file test.txt (or indeed test.bin).

Windows 10 defender silently deletes netcat from machines for convenience and security.

I dont want to tell defender to ignore netcat on every machine I use, or fight with it to install netcat in the first place.

Is there a simple command line alternative to achieve the same thing with Windows?  Or a variant of netcat that doesnt annoy virus checkers yet allows this command?

Answer (score -1):

NMAP appears to fit the bill:

https://nmap.org/ncat/

installs netcat for the 21st century..

Comment: Welcome! Great that you found a tool that works for you. Just note that 1) link-only answers are not valid answers; 2) tool/product recommendation questions are off-topic here, and 3) this isn't a programming question - general computing questions belong on SuperUser.